# Is there a way to access event data generated by Firebase Analytics in order to send it to third-party analytics solutions?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am setting up analytics for my mobile app and already have Firebase Analytics implemented. I want to catch the event data generated by Firebase Analytics and re-send it to third-party tracking solutions (like Amplitude). Is there a way to access this data the same way it's done for web (by accessing dataLayer parameters)?